# Seg fault with open command when trying to open very large file

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, gdb

I'm taking a networking class at school and am using C/GDB for the first time. Our assignment is to make a webserver that communicates with a client browser. I am well underway and can open files and send them to the client. Everything goes great till I open a very large file and then I seg fault. I'm not a pro at C/GDB so I'm sorry if that is causing me to ask silly questions and not be able to see the solution myself but when I looked at the dumped core I see my seg fault comes here:

```
if (-1 == (openfd = open(path, O_RDONLY)))
```

Specifically we are tasked with opening the file and the sending it to the client browser. My Algorithm goes:

1. Open/Error catch
2. Read the file into a buffer/Error catch
3. Send the file

We were also tasked with making sure that the server doesn't crash when SENDING very large files. But my problem seems to be with opening them. I can send all my smaller files just fine. The file in question is 29.5MB.

The whole algorithm is:

```
ssize_t send_file(int conn, char *path, int len, int blksize, char *mime) {
  int openfd; // File descriptor for file we open at path
  int temp; // Counter for the size of the file that we send
  char buffer[len]; // Buffer to read the file we are opening that is len big

  // Open the file
  if (-1 == (openfd = open(path, O_RDONLY))) {
    send_head(conn, "", 400, strlen(ERROR_400));
    (void) send(conn, ERROR_400, strlen(ERROR_400), 0);
    logwrite(stdout, CANT_OPEN);
    return -1;
  }

  // Read from file
  if (-1 == read(openfd, buffer, len)) {
    send_head(conn, "", 400, strlen(ERROR_400));
    (void) send(conn, ERROR_400, strlen(ERROR_400), 0);
    logwrite(stdout, CANT_OPEN);
    return -1;
  }
  (void) close(openfd);

  // Send the buffer now
  logwrite(stdout, SUC_REQ);
  send_head(conn, mime, 200, len);      
  send(conn, &buffer[0], len, 0);
  return len;
}
```

I dunno if it is just a fact that a I am Unix/C novice. Sorry if it is. =( But you're help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show some code around it. Better yet, write a minimal program that exhibits the issue.

Comment: As long as `path` is a pointer to the first character of a NUL-terminated string in readable memory, I cannot imagine a segfault on that line.  (And under many circumstances, `open` will more likely return -1 and set `errno=EFAULT`.)  Are you **sure** that's the faulting line?

Comment: It might not be. I don't know how to use GDB or the Unix environ for that matter much yet. But when I type this in gdb webserver webserver.core it says Program Terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault. It the line if (-1 == (openfd = open(path, O_RDONLY)) line. Im presuming thats the cause

Comment: OH DEAR.  `char buffer[len]` -- Please don't allocate huge arrays (or huge anything) on the stack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a variable length array, perhaps try allocated the memory using `malloc`.

```
char *buffer = malloc (len);

...

free (buffer);
```

I just did some simple tests on my system, and when I use variable length arrays of a big size (like the size you're having trouble with), I also get a SEGFAULT.

Comment: When should I decide to malloc space versus using a variable length array? And if I do use a variable length array whats the largest I can make it? Maybe thats to vague but that seems to be part of my problem here.

Comment: Variable length arrays are usually implemented by making space on the stack, and the stack of a program is usually very little in comparison to how much memory you can get from `malloc`. The largest VLA you can make depends on how much stack space the operating system gives your process. You should generally keep variable length arrays quite small, 4 kilobytes is usually as far as I go and even then I get worried that I've asked too much, although some systems have quite large stacks, around 4 MB or sometimes even 8 MB, but it is system-dependent.

Comment: Personally, I hate using variable-length arrays that are allocated on the stack. I mean, the very fact that it's system-dependent sort of implies that it might not be deterministic, at least across different systems. Using the heap and malloc, I can feel more confident that I'll either get the amount I want, or run out of memory if the system is low at that time. Incidentally, you only get a certain amount of memory in the heap anyway, so if you're dealing with a REALLY large file (>4GB on a 32-bit system) the computer will spit in your face if you try this method, hence my buffer solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible I'm just misunderstanding what you meant in your question, but I feel I should point out that in general, it's a bad idea to try to read the entire file at once, in case you deal with something that's just too big for your memory to handle.

It's smarter to allocate a buffer of a specific size, say 8192 bytes (well, that's what I tend to do a lot, anyway), and just always read and send that much, as much as necessary, until your read() operation returns 0 (and no errno set) for end of stream.

Comment: Not bad, but I tend to use 10240.

Comment: Fair enough. I just like powers of 2, I guess.

Comment: @Richard: Why 10240? That's not a power of 2.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: You're not alone. Many programmers I know also find powers of 2 more logical to work with.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a power of 2, but it should be some multiple of 8192 since most memory pages are either 4096 or 8192 bytes in size, the exception being some PPC64 systems that use a page size of 65536.

Comment: @Chris: Because not everyone remembers 16384, or 1048576 for that matter.

Comment: @Ignacio: Also, disk sectors are usually between 512 and 4096 bytes each.

Comment: I will change this, as you bring up a good point. Imma wait till I fix my open problem as I got everything working for smaller files. I presume sending the huge file will create a problem if I send all of it at once so I will have to fix that too.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have a stackoverflow (I should get bonus points for using that term on this site).

The problem is you are allocating the buffer for the entire file on the stack all at once.  For larger files, this buffer is larger than the stack, and the next time you try to call a function (and thus put some parameters for it on the stack) the program crashes.

The crash appears at the open line because allocating the buffer on the stack doesn't actually write any memory, it just changes the stack pointer.  When your call to open tries tow rite the parameters to the stack, the top of the stack is now overflown and this causes a crash.

The solution is as Platinum Azure or dreamlax suggest, read in the file little bits at a time or allocate your buffer on the heap will malloc or new.

Comment: Unless you use C99's VLAs or `alloca`, it's not actually very easy to allocate a variable amount of stack space.  I like like this hypothesis.... oh.  I see that OP has edited their question to include code, and they are using VLAs.  Bad OP!  And +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating the buffer on the stack, and it's way too big.

When you allocate storage on the stack, all the compiler does is decrease the stack pointer enough to make that much room (this keeps stack variable allocation to constant time).  It does not try to touch any of this stacked memory.  Then, when you call `open()`, it tries to put the parameters on the stack and discovers it has overflowed the stack and dies.

You need to either operate on the file in chunks, memory-map it (`mmap()`), or `malloc()` storage.
Also, `path` should be declared `const char*`.

Comment: A sliding `mmap` window takes some effort, but can be pretty awesome :)  (Why not map the whole file?  Well, sometimes you only have 2GB of virtual address space and you want to work on a 8GB file...)

Comment: yeah, but Chris said 23.5 MB, so I suggested the minimum complexity solution.